# Idenfity what device the below error happened with the icons displayed on input fields

Tags: icons, input-field

I received the request from client service requesting to investigate about the issue from a screenshot sent by a customer. However I met difficulties in identifying what device / platform / browser the customer has used to reproduce it; and hardly can get it from the requester:
[image]

From the screenshot, I can pretty sure that this was captured after a registration failure (due to javascript error/disabled). So the cursor moved to the First Name field - the reason why the icon showed. And **the icons were not of the web site**, so I guess they were from the native-ness of the device/browser. Not sure if it is filled by browser's add-on.

Have you ever met such icons? Could you help me identify the device / platform / browser they might use ? Any light is appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a snapshot of the same page from your native browser, that can help comparing with what you received from client & might help us figuring out the device / platform / browser. To me it looks like an iPAD device running Safari, though not very sure

Comment: Can you access the webpage from the internet? Then you could use a service to test the webpage in all available browsers. Like in [crossbrowsertesting](https://crossbrowsertesting.com) or [browserling](https://www.browserling.com) or [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/list-of-browsers-and-platforms?product=live)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recognize this as the [LastPass extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lastpass-free-password-ma/hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd?hl=en-US), a password manager. In particular, the icon on the First Name field can be clicked to automatically fill in the whole form, and the icons on the password fields will automatically generate a random password using the extension.

It looks like the LastPass extension is available for various browsers, and the form icons appear to be the same for all of them, so that doesn't really offer much insight for what device and browser they're using. I *am* positive that it's not something built into the browser.

Comment: I can confirm it, this should be an accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for everybody's attention. Answer accepted :)